# Basic Concepts of Language Type Systems

Tags: programming-languages, terminology, type-systems

Could someone please explain clearly and succinctly the concepts of language type systems? 
I've read a post or two here on type systems, but have trouble finding one that answers all my questions below.

I've heard/read that there are 3 type categorizations: dynamic vs static, strong vs weak, safe vs unsafe.

Some questions:

- Are there any others?
- What do each of these mean?
- If a language allows you to change the type of a variable in runtime (e.g. a variable that used to store an int is later used to store a string), what category does that fall in?
- How does Python fit into each of these categories?
- Is there anything else I should know about type systems?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Apparently, there are others: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system

2)

`Dynamic` => Type checking is done during runtime (program execution) e.g. Python.

`Static` (as opposed to Dynamic) => Type checking is done during compile time e.g. C++

`Strong` => Once the type system decides that a particular object is of a type, it doesn't allow it to be used as another type. e.g. Python

`Weak` (as opposed to Strong) => The type system allows objects types to change. e.g. perl lets you read a number as a string, then use it again as a number

`Type safety` => I can only best describe with a 'C' statement like:

```
x = (int *) malloc (...);
```

`malloc` returns a (void *) and we simply type-cast it to (int *). At compile time there is no check that the pointer returned by the function malloc will actually be the size of an integer => Some C operations aren't type safe.

I am told that some 'purely functional' languages are inherently type safe, but I do not know any of these languages. I think Standard ML or Haskell would be type safe.

3) "If a language allows you to change the type of a variable in runtime (e.g. a variable that used to store an int is later used to store a string), what category does that fall in?":

This may be dynamic - variables are untyped, values may carry implicit or explicit type information; alternatively, the type system may be able to cope with variables that change type, and be a static type system.

4) Python: It's dynamically and strongly typed. Type safety is something *I* don't know python (and type safety itself) enough to say anything about.

5) "Is there anything else I should know about type systems?": Maybe read the book @BasileStarynkevitch suggests?

Comment: As to your answer to #3, I'd say that's "dynamically typed". Consider it this way... if the language allows you to change the type of a VARIABLE (name of the value) at runtime, that's dynamic typing. If the language allows you to change the type of a VALUE (have a string "1" and treat is as an integer), that's weak typing.

Comment: @RHSeeger - You are right. That is what I meant to say, and then mixed up :(. Corrected now.

Comment: @RHSeeger - No. I recant that. I meant weak typing. However, because I'm not an expert and I have no sources to cite an authoritative answer, I will ignore that part of the question :)

Comment: Perl's handling of ints as strings is not an example of weak typing, because it actually substitutes in a different value. Perl is strongly typed, with implicit conversions. Weak typing is when, for example, C allows an int to be treated as a pointer (or indeed when it allows pointer arithmetic).

Comment: Python is not strongly typed, nor safe. Variables can have different typed values at different times. Class objects can have different methods at various times.

Comment: @Yttrill: The official Python wiki says it is strongly typed: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language and Wikipedia says it is strongly typed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29

Answer (score 2):

You are asking a lot here :) Type system is a dedicated field of computer science!

Starting from the begining, "a type system is method for proving the absence of certain program behavior" (See [B.Pierce's Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/), also referred in the other answer). Programs that pass the type checking is a *subset* of what would be valid programs. For instance, the method

```
int answer() {
   if(true) { return 42; } else { return "wrong"; }
}
```

would actually behave well at run-time. The else branch is never executed, and the answer always return 42. The static type system is a *conservative* analysis that will reject this program, because it can not prove the absence of a type error, that is, that "wrong" is never returned.

Of course, you could improve the type system to actually detect that the else branch never happens. You want to improve the type system to reject as few program as possible. This is why type system have been enriched over the years to support more and more refinement (e.g. generic, etc.)

The point of a type system is to prove the absence of type errors. In practice, they support operations like downcasting that inherently imply run-time type checks, and might lead to type errors. Again, the goal is to make the type system as flexible as possible, so that we don't need to resort to these operations that weaken type safety (e.g. generic).

You can read chapter 1 of the aforementionned book for a really nice introduction. For the rest, I will refer you to [What To Know Before Debating Type Systems](http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2010/08/what-to-know-before-debating-type-systems.html), which is awesome blog post about the basic concepts.

> Is there anything else I should know about type systems?

Oh, yes! :)

Happy immersion in the world of type systems!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading [B.Pierce's *Types and Programming Languages*](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) book. And I also suggest learning a bit of a statically-typed, with type inference, language like Ocaml or Haskell.

Comment: While your suggestions are certainly useful on the long run (at least the latter bit, I haven't read that book), you don't answer the question. Well, except the last question perhaps.

Comment: Since your question takes an entire book to be answered, I believe you might not expect a full answer given in a few minutes.

Comment: (It's not my question, but apart from that:) A summary should be sufficent for a beginner, at least for the first few questions. The last one is indeed quite broad.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I understand you point of view, but pointing to this book is not so useful to the reader. Only chapter 1 might interest him. For the rest, I guess there are other concepts to understand first I guess, e.g. what is generics/parametric polymorphism, and why we want it.

Answer (score 0):

A type system is a mechanism which controls the functions which access values. Compile time checking is one aspect of this, which rejects programs during compilation if an attempt is made to use a function on values it is not designed to handle. However another aspect is the converse, the selection of functions to handle some values, for example overloading. Another example is specialisation of polymorphic functions (e.g. templates in C++). Inference and deduction are other aspects where the type of functions is deduced by usage rather than specified by the programmer.

Parts of the checking and selection can be deferred until run time. Dispatch of methods based on variant tags or by indirection or specialised tables as for C++ virtual functions or Haskell typeclass dictionaries are two examples provided even in extremely strongly typed languages.

The key concept of type systems is called *soundness*. A type system is sound if it guarantees no value can be used by an inappropriate function. Roughly speaking an unsound type system has "holes" and is useless. The type system of ISO C89 is sound if you remove casts (and void* conversions), and unsound if you allow them. The type system of ISO C++ is unsound.

A second vital concept of types systems is called *expressiveness*. Sound type systems for polymorphic programming prevent programmers writing valid code: they're universally too restrictive (and I believe inescapably so). Making type systems more expressive so they allow a wider set of valid programs is the key academic challenge.

Another concept of typing is *strength*. A strong type system can find more errors earlier. For example many languages have type systems too weak to detect array bounds violations using the type system and have to resort to run time checks. Somehow strength is the opposite of expressiveness: we want to allow more valid programs (expressiveness) but also catch even more invalid ones (strength).

Here's a key question: explain why OO typing is too weak to permit OO to be used as a general development paradigm. [Hint: OO cannot handle relations]