# What is the benefit of having many different data types?

Tags: python, types, pyqt, qwt

What is the benefit of using many different data types in a language? I have been working with pyqt and pyqwt recently and I keep finding myself typing lines like this:

```
grid.setPen(Qt.QPen(Qt.Qt.gray, 0, Qt.Qt.DotLine))
curve.setSymbol(Qwt.QwtSymbol(Qwt.QwtSymbol.Ellipse,
                              Qt.QBrush(),
                              Qt.QPen(Qt.Qt.black),
                              Qt.QSize(5, 5)))
```

What would be lost if the above lines were instead the following?:

```
grid.setPen('gray', 0 ,'dotted')
curve.setSymbol('ellipse', 'k', (5,5))
```

Even if the specific types are needed for some technical reason, couldn't the strings be converted to those types inside the method that needs them?

Is this because pyqt and pyqwt are simply bindings for C++ libraries? If so why are they needed in C++?

Comment: It's just impossible and shows you didn't think things through. The way you proposed it, every function would have to know about everything. Reconsider your question, this way it's hilarious.

Comment: I apologize if this question comes of as hilarious, I am self taught in programming and do not know much theory. Could you explain why its so dumb? The first programming language I learned was Matlab, which allows you to do exactly what I stated: plot(x, 'r-')

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type contained some answers already, and you could have found it easily even without a formal computer science education. See also my reply.

Comment: You should evaluate and perhaps accept some answers.

Comment: @DonQuestion It is not hilarious imho. which is then the normal python format for functions and methods?

Comment: @joaquin: quote: "Even if the specific types are needed ... couldn't the strings be converted ... inside the method that needs them?" We are not passing TYPES but OBJECTS! That's why his question is hilarious. He wants the called method to be a factory and much more. So why even bother with methods or arguments? It's not a law to use them, but there are good reasons why the things are how they are and that's not something you can explain in a single answer. You need to  gain understanding by studying and experimenting yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few benefits:

1. Type safe languages (like C++) have the advantage that many errors are found at compile time (as opposed to run-time). That means using Qt.grey (note the e) would fail to compile because the type is not defined.
2. Better performance and less memory. Behind the scenes Qt.gray is a number, and number operations are much faster than strings.

In the pyqt case, because the library wraps a C++ library it looks more like c++ than like Python code.

Comment: Since python isn't a compiled language does that mean the only benefit is better performance?

Comment: Technically, many strings in Python are numbers behind the scenes as well (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

Comment: The Python interpreter is parsing the script, and is interpreting something different than a file (usually, some kind of abstract syntax tree...), so some errors can be found when parsing the script.

Answer (score 3):

Different types let you check at *compile* time (at least, in C++) that you're passing the right kinds of things - for instance, if everything took strings, it'd be very easy to accidentally typo `'gray'` as, say, `'grey'`, and possibly confuse the library.

A normal pattern is to do something more like this:

```
greypen = Qt.QPen(Qt.Qt.gray, 0, Qt.Qt.DotLine)
blackpen = Qt.QPen(Qt.Qt.black, 0, Qt.Qt.DotLine)
# ...
grid.setPen(greypen)
# ...
grid.setPen(blackpen)
```

That way you don't wind up repeating yourself if you're using the same kinds of attributes multiple times.

Comment: Why is a 'grey' -> 'gray' typo worse than a Qt.Qt.grey -> Qt.Qt.gray one? Both seem just as easy to make. Since python is interpreted are both these errors caught at the same time?

Comment: No, because the interpretation is changing the script file into some internal representation as soon as it loads it -before running it-, and during that change (you can call it parsing) some error detection happens.

Comment: @jminardi No, one would be caught inside the method call, one would be caught before hand. Also, it would rely on the method call itself to do all the conversions--and *every* method call would have to perform the same conversions. By defining a constant value available throughout the code, methods become simpler, typos can be caught by an IDE, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's because they are objects
if you use this QPen::QPen ()
then what it does is Construct a default black solid line pen with 0 width.
but since it's overloaded you can use parameters for those constructors
when you pass a parameter in the QPen class what you send is processed and the result would return.  so those are concepts of object orientations. you need to make an instance 
and that instance will handle the underlying part of it. if you use a string parameter like what you've used in the second example it will just use string type instead Qt.QPen() type.
setPen() function asks for an object typed QPen() not string typed variable.
the advantage is you don't need to write everything from ground floor. and some parts are predefined like a video game. in video game you can't do a lot of functions. if you shoot at someone he will shoot you or run away so the reaction is depend on the action you make.
the action is the parameter and reaction is the return value from one of functions in that class. behind the scene there might a ton of codes which do various tasks. like how he reacts, the timing, whether he runs or walk or fly when you shoot so those are set at default value unless you change them specially. sometimes you don't need to change those default values or it would take time.in that case just pass the action and get the reaction. that's what this does. it's really useful for complex programs.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you make a typo, or a spelling mistake. So for example you write *Elipse* instead of *Ellipse*.

If you code with `Qwt.QwtSymbol.Elipse` the error would be caught before running.

If you code with strings like `'elipse'` the error cannot be caught before runtime, and would only be caught when actually calling `setSymbol` (so if that call appear in an `else` branch you never take in your particular run, the error will stay unnoticed).

And of course, there are also performance reasons.

There are whole books on this [typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) question. You could e.g. learn a bit of [Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/index.en.html) and read [*Types and Programming Languages*](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) by B.Pierce.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8617603/841108).

Answer (score 0):

I'm really surprised, that the question got upvotes. Why? Does it show  research effort? No! Maybe the OP did research, but he didn't make it obvious.Is it useful? Is it clear? It's clear he has a problem with passing anonymous objects. But why should his personal struggle in gaining knowledge be useful?

You are wondering why you have to take so much "effort" in typing superfluos code, just to make a simple dotted gray ellipse.
First you must keep in mind, that with "Qt" you are using an object-oriented framework. So terminology and conceptual wise you are using a set of classes from which you instantiate objects. What you would call types are the classes.

In your example you don't do the following:

grid.setPen(Qt.Pen)

Which would pass to setPen the **TYPE** `Qt.Pen`, but you define an **object**. Contrary to classes objects contains individual values: 5(=`Qt.gray`), 0, 3(=`Qt.DotLine`). This is an oversimplification, but it's just to drive the point home.

*Like the "`type`" `integer` says, that every object of this type (class) can contain whole-number values it doesn't contain the individual values itself. But it defines that every instance of the `type` (class) `integer` MUST hold whole-number values. The integer-variables hold instances (objects) of the class with individual values.*

Back to your example, you create an object of the class (type) `QtPen`, which the method `setPen` does know to handle:

grid.setPen(Qt.QPen(Qt.Qt.gray, 0, Qt.Qt.DotLine))

Your object just happens to be of the class(type) `Qt.Pen`. So you are not just passing a **TYPE** but you are passing the **three values you explicitly** mentioned as arguments **PLUS a TON of other** useful stuff implicitly with the object (e.g. CapStyle, MiterLimit, JoinStyle ...)

In python there is no implicit type-checking of arguments. So you could pass, what you proposed:

grid.setPen('gray', 0 ,'dotted')

BUT the method expects some objects which it's familar with and knows how to handle them. A string-OBJECT it **doesn't know** to handle. So it would be **YOUR** job to explain what it should do. So you would either have to **subclass `Qt.Pen`** with a constructor which can handle your strings, or modify the Qt.Pen class directly and **recompiling** QT afterwards.

I concede the `Qt.Pen` class is not the optimal example. So we could create a better example to illustrate the underlying concepts and where you are under false assumptions.

But first i would claim that your "surrogate" question originates from a major confusion to understand the object-oriented paradigm, but couldn't discern the source of your confussion in the lack of greater insight - it's the chicken/egg problem.

There are many roads to rome, which you take is yours to decide. But with the decision to use "Qt" you already decided on a general set of roads. And those are build for **objects**.

Let us assume we want to draw some houses. So we define a method `draw_house` using the `magical_drawing_routine` (which by the way is exactly what you were looking for at your original question):

```
def draw_house(house):
        magical_drawing_routine(house)

draw_house('parentshome')
draw_house('myhome')
```

Now we got exactly two identical drawn houses without doors, windows or the lovely chimney of our parent's home. (And we are completely ignoring how the `magical_drawin_routine` knows how to interprete the string-values)

Back to the drawing board we would correct the lack of these:

```
def draw_house(door, window, chimney):
    magical_drawing_routine(door, window, chimney)

parentshome = ['oak', 'green', 'yes']
myhome = ['beech', 'red', 'no']
draw_house(parentshome)
draw_house(myhome)
```

Now we got exactly two identical drawn houses with doors, windows and the lovely chimney of our parent's home.But wait, the windows and doors have the exact same shape. Back to the drawing board...

after some cylces you would have something like:

```
def draw_house(doormaterial, doorcolor, doorshape, doorwithglass, doorglassparts, windowsnumber, widnowsdistributionpattern, windowsencassing, windowmaterial, windowshape, windowpattern, windowdecoration, chimney):
   ...
```

or we could define classes: `class House, class Window, class Door, class Chimney` with reasonable default-values.

```
pdoor, mdoor = Door(a,b), Door(a,Z) 
pwin, mwin = Window(e,f,g), Window(e,f,Y)
pchimney, mchimney = Chimney(h), Chimney(X)

parentshome = House(pdoor, pwin, pchimney)
myhome = House(mdoor, mwin, mchimney)
```

if your using the door for your parent only one time, you can forgoe the pdoor definition and instantiate the object on-the-fly while passing the arguments, by gerenating an anonymous object (no variable attached):
parentshome = House(Door(...), ...)

So the simple answer is: **you don't pass types**! **You pass objects**, which normaly **encapsulte complexities**. But for awful simple objects it might look like your overcomplicating simple stuff - but that is just how it looks like.

Comment: I am not sure it is the right answer, because the called function (e.g. `setPen`) must know (or at least must handle) about all variations on its argument. Some scripting languages (e.g. *Tcl* which I don't like) accept mostly strings.